# Add words at beginning and end of a FASTA header line with sed

Tags: sed, fasta

I have the following line:

```
>XXX-220_5004_COVID-A6
TTTATTTGACATGAGTAAATTTCCCCTTAAATTAAGGGGTACTGCTGTTATGTCTTTAAA
AGAAGGTCAAATCAATGATATGATTTTATCTCTTCTTAGTAAAGGTAGACTTATAATTAG
AGAAAACAAC
```

I would like to convert the first line as follows:

```
>INITWORD/XXX-220_5004_COVID-A6/FINALWORD
TTTATTTGACATGAGTAAATTTCCCCTTAAATTAAGGGGTACTGCTGTTATGTCTTTAAA
AGAAGGT...
```

So far I have managed to add the first word as follows:

```
sed 's/>/>INITTWORD\//I'
```

That returns:

```
>INITWORD/XXX-220_5004_COVID-A6
    TTTATTTGACATGAGTAAATTTCCCCTTAAATTAAGGGGTACTGCTGTTATGTCTTTAAA
    AGAAGGT
```

How can i add the FINALWORD at the end of the first line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just substitute more. `sed` conveniently allows you to recall the text you matched with a back reference, so just embed that between the things you want to add.

```sh
sed 's%^>\(.*\)%>INITWORD/\1/FINALWORD%I' file.fasta
```

I also added a `^` beginning-of-line anchor, and switched to `%` delimiters so the slashes don't need to be escaped.

In some more detail, the `s` command's syntax is `s/regex/replacement/flags` where `regex` is a regular expression to match the text you want to replace, and `replacement` is the text to replace it with.  In the regex, you can use grouping parentheses `\(...\)` to extract some of the matched text into the replacement; so `\1` refers to whatever matched the first set of grouping parentheses, `\2` to the second, etc.  The `/flags` are optional single-character specifiers which modify the behavior of the command; so for example, a `/g` flag says to replace every match on a line, instead of just the first one (but we only expect one match per line so it's not necessary or useful here).

The `I` flag is non-standard but since you are using that, I assume it does something useful for you.

Comment: I would suggest to use the beginng of line `^` instead of `<`

Comment: Great !!! I thought the I was to add the word to the beg of the file.

Comment: @ivan Huh? I use `^` but the `>` is also necessary because that's what marks a line as a FASTA header line.

Comment: I can't tell you what `I` flag does because it's non-standard; I'm guessing maybe it makes the match case-insensitive (which doesn't do anything in this particular case, because you have no alphabetics in the regex). Probably review your local `sed` manual page.

Comment: @tripleee my bad! I thought OP wanted  `INITWORD>` instead of  `>INITWORD`